# Longest common prefixes in a set of binary strings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bit-strings

Consider a set $D$ of $n$ uniformly random binary strings of length $m$.

Fix $l \leq m$.

We now sample an $m$-bit string uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}^m$. Let $\alpha$ be the $l$-bit prefix of this string. I'm interested in the probability that $\alpha$ is the longest common prefix between two strings in $D$. How can this be calculated? Is there a closed-form formula?

Comment: Nitpick, but why not just sample $\alpha$ uniformly from $\{0,1\}^l$? Also, is $D$ the result of sampling exactly $n$ times (possibly giving fewer than $n$ distinct strings) or of sampling until there are exactly $n$ different results?

Comment: Hint: What's the probability that a random string starts with $\alpha$? What's the probability that exactly $k$ of $n$ random strings start with $\alpha$? Given $k$ strings that start with $\alpha$, what's the probability that their common prefix is longer than $\alpha$?